# How to include pipeline errors in email (Email-ext plugin)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to have the reason as it is printed on the console of my Jenkins instance why a build failed through email. I did the following

```
node {
    try 
    {
     stage('checkout') {
      checkout scm
       }
     stage('restore') {
      sh 'dotnetge restore test.sln'
       }
    }
    catch (err) {
       cause=err
       emailext body:"Error: $cause ",
        to: 'myemail@gmail.com'
    }
}
```

The result on the console is something like "dotnetge command not found" and i will like to have this same type of error through email. This is what i get through email

Error: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 127

Comment: Can you please share more of your code and console output, with the exact command that is failing and your stage and try - catch structure, to give a better understanding of your issue. I am doing the same thing and it works fine for me.

Comment: Hi i just edited my post. it contains the full post.I was expecting to see "dotnetge: command not found" in my email. But i get Error: hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 127

Answer (score 0):

Since the shell script failed, it will give the exception you are currently getting. You can have a workaround to handle this:

```
node {
    try
    {
        stage('checkout') {
            checkout scm
        }
        stage('restore') {
            try{
                sh 'dotnetge restore test.sln'}
            catch(exc){
                error "dotnetge command failed"
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        cause=err
        emailext body:"Error: $cause ",
                to: 'myemail@gmail.com'
    }
}
```

This way you can at least know which command failed. What else I did was that I created another variable called `curr_stage` and assigned its value to the current stage:

```
node{
    def curr_stage
    try {
        stage("stage1") {
            curr_stage = "stage1"
        }
        stage("stage2") {
            curr_stage = "stage2"
        }
        stage("stage3") {
            curr_stage = "stage3"
        }
    }catch(exception){
        //notify that the the build failed at ${curr_stage}
    }
}
```